# When does a representation admit a spin structure?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional *real* representation of $G$.  Think of $V$ as given by a homomorphism
$$ \rho_V\colon G\to O(n).$$
Write $\chi_V$ for the character of $V$.

Here are two problems.

1. Using *only* the character $\chi_V$ of $V$, determine whether $\rho_V(G)\subset SO(n)$.
2. Using *only* the character $\chi_V$ of $V$, and assuming $\rho_V(G)\subset SO(n)$, determine whether $\rho_V$ admits a factorization through a homomorphism $\widetilde{\rho}_V:G\to Spin(n)$.

Here's one answer to 1: the identity of formal power series
$$ \sum_{k\geq0} \chi_{\Lambda^kV}(g)\,T^k = \exp\Bigl( -\sum_{k\geq1} \frac{1}{k}\chi_V(g^k)\, (-T)^k \Bigr)$$
where $\Lambda^kV$ is the $k$-th exterior power representation of $V$,  gives $\chi_{\Lambda^nV}(g)$ as a polynomial in $\chi_V(g),\dots,\chi_V(g^n)$, and $\rho_V(G)\subset SO(n)$ if and only if all $\chi_{\Lambda^nV}(g)>0$.

Is there a better answer for 1?  Is there any answer in a similar spirit for 2?

Comment: I guess there is a cohomological obstruction  for 2 in $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. Although, I have no idea how
to express this in character theory.

Comment: I don't think that any such answer exists for (2).  The obstruction to lifting is called the second Steifel-Whitney class of the orthogonal real representation $\rho_V$, written $w_2(\rho_V)$.  It's difficult to compute and quite important for Galois representations (related to $\epsilon$-factors).  Such results lie beyond simple character calculuations, I think.  Compare, for instance, the problem of deciding whether a rep. into $SO(3)$ arises as $Sym^2$ of a rep into $SU(2)$.  Can you tell by the character?    

Comment: (I suppose that the $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ case is just the case $n = 3$ of the question...)

Comment: Okay.  But I don't see why, a priori, having a cohomological obstruction means you can't compute it from the character; my question 1 is really about the vanishing of $w_1(\rho_V)$, after all.    On the other hand, I could certainly believe that such a problem could be intractible.

Comment: Here's another reason why such an answer shouldn't exist for (2).  Let's say you know all the eigenvalues for $\rho(g)$, $\rho(g^2)$, etc., information given by the character.  Well, that information tells you nothing about whether $\rho$ factors through the 2-fold Spin cover, because *every* element of $SO(n)$ lifts (compatibly with its powers) to an element of $Spin(n)$.  Instead, you need information about $\rho(g_1), \rho(g_2), \rho(g_1 g_2)$ for all pairs $(g_1, g_2)$ -- information depending probably on the conjugacy class of the pair $(g_1, g_2)$ (not individual conjugacy classes).

Comment: @marty : are you saying that any morphism $Z/kZ \to SO(n)$ lifts $Spin(n)$ ? This seems not true if $k$ is even.

Comment: @BS:  Ah yes.. that was dumb on my part.  I had in mind the lifting of subgroups isomorphic to $Z$, not $Z / kZ$, when I wrote that.  The remainder of my comment -- that one needs information about pairs, not just individual elements -- should hold (though it's vague). 

Comment: Marty, your observation about pairs of conjugacy classes seems convincing to me.

Comment: Charles, I can see at least a necessary condition on the character (that you probably know of). It is that for any involution $s\in G$, $\chi_V(s)\equiv\chi_V(1) \mod 8$ (this comes from restriction to cyclic subgroups). Given the "miracles" of Brauer theory, might it be sufficient also ? A perhaps relevant reference is this Deligne's 1976 [paper][1], related to Marty's first remark about $\epsilon$ factors.


  [1]: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002092654

Comment: For 1, it depends what you mean by "using the character ONLY". You can't tell the number of elements of each order from the character alone. If you do know the order of each element, then 1 requires just that each element of $G$ has the eigenvalue $-1$ with even (possibly zero) multiplicity, and this is an easy calculation, given the character values ( in fact, you only need to check elements whose order is a power of $2$).